# 2 dimensional value prediction with Tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, tensorflow, estimators

I have searched long and couldn't find a solution yet. I have a data-set with 3 input signals, which produce irregular values and an associated relative 2-dimensional position (x and y).

I want to build a Tensorflow estimator to predict based on these 3 input values the position of x and y for samples in which I only have the 3 input signals. The values are stored in a panda Series.

```
pd.Series('index' = [0,1,..., 100], 'value' = [-45, -38, ..., -90], 'signal_source' = ['Jimmy', 'Bob', ..., 'Bob'], 'x_position' = [2, 2, ..., 5], 'y_position’ = [3, 3, ..., 1])
```

I couldn't find a tensorflow estimator outputting 2 numerical values and optimizing the output to the euclidean distance of the predicted position to the real position. Is there a name for this kind of problem or can anyone help me building such an estimator please.